unittest.mock patch decorator is not called depending on the pytest target
Running
docker compose -f docker-compose.local.yml run --rm django pytest ./project/app/

the following test passes perfectly, meaning patch method is being used
@patch("project.app.pluggy_integration.utils.generate_connect_token", autospec=True)
def test_get_token(self, mock_get_user_portfolio_data):
    mock_token = "ABCD" 
    mock_get_user_portfolio_data.return_value = mock_token 
    response = self.client.get(url_call)    
    mock_get_user_portfolio_data.assert_called_once()
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK

HOWEVER, when running pytest for the whole project, this specific test fails:
docker compose -f docker-compose.local.yml run --rm django pytest
or
docker compose -f docker-compose.local.yml run --rm django pytest project/

the mock method is not used and the test fails. Error:
AssertionError: Expected 'generate_connect_token' to have been called once. Called 0 times.

my docker compose file is located at
~\src\docker-compose.local.yml

and the test is located at
~\src\project\app\tests\test_api_views.py

Appreciate your help!
